# Instantiating template classes with template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

I have three classes:

```
//Template class for function 1
template<class P> class wrap4{
    P p;

public:
    wrap4(P&& p1) : p(std::forward<P>(p1)) {}

    double f(double x){
        return p.FN(x);
    }

};

//Simple concrete parameter
struct Parameter{
    double FN(double x){
        return x;
    }

};

//Method used in the program
template<class Function> class B {
    Function F;
public:
    B(Function && f) : F(std::forward<Function>(f)) {}
    double use(double x){
        return F.f(x);
    }
}; 

template<class Function> B<Function> make_B(Function && F){ return B<Function>{std::forward<Function>(F)}; }
template<class P> B<P> make_wrap4(P && F){ return B<P>{std::forward<P>(F)}; }
```

Basically, I want to plug `wrap4` into `B`, but to do so I have to instantiate it with `Parameter`. I've tried the following:

```
auto A = make_B(make_wrap4{Parameter p});
```

but this doesn't work, I get the compiler error

```
error: conversion from 'B<B<Parameter> >' to non-scalar type 'B<wrap4<Parameter> >' requested
```

Of course, this is a silly example because I know I can just implement `B` with `Parameter`, but of course I'm trying to do something more complicated in the long run where I really need a `B` to take a template class which doesn't admit a default constructor as an argument.

Do I need to implement a template template parameter here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a copy&paste error you should be able to spot from the error message:

```
template<class P> B<P> make_wrap4(P && F){ return B<P>{std::forward<P>(F)}; }
```

should be

```
template<class P> wrap4<P> make_wrap4(P && F){ return wrap4<P>{std::forward<P>(F)}; }
//                ^^ here                             ^^ and here
```

and then you should call `make_wrap4` like a function, i.e. not with an initializer list.

---

A little sidenote: you don't have three classes, you have one class and two *class templates*. It's also not a *template class*, as the comment states for `wrap4`.

- `wrap4` is a *class template*.
- `wrap4<int>` and `wrap4<Parameter>` are *classes*, which you get by instantiating the class template. Some people would call such classes *template class* as well.

Comment: Thanks! That was a pretty retarded mistake :D Also, thanks for the notes.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for being nitpicking, but there are times when such things make the difference between understanding and not understanding a problem, especially on SO ;)

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was being honest when I said thanks! I'm quite new to templates - which I think are brilliant - there are many nuances still unknown to me.